# "State of Maryland" or "state of Maryland"?

Tags: capitalization

When referring to a U.S. state in a formal document, is it correct to capitalize "State," or should it remain uncapitalized?

For example:

This school is accredited by the State of Maryland
OR
This school is accredited by the state of Maryland

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to follow the [State of Maryland](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22state+of+maryland%22+site%3Aedu&oq=%22state+of+maryland%22+site%3Aedu&aqs=chrome..69i57.17510j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=%22state+of+maryland%22+site%3amaryland.gov)'s lead, you should say State of Maryland. Also, I would say if you're using the phrase as an honorific symbolizing deference (as is the case in law), use "State of Maryland."

But really, unless this is to be used in financial, governmental, or official records, both are acceptable and used.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how the link to the website supports the notion that the state of Maryland uses "State of Maryland." I couldn't find anything there that used the phrase, except in a title, and we can't judge correct capitalization practices based on a title.

Comment: @J.R. Well I posted because while browsing the website for a bit most instances I saw capitalized "State." I've updated the link to show the pages with examples. I thought linking to the site would be better than linking 50 of the subpages with examples.

Comment: I didn't ask for 50 links, but one or two would've been nice :^) (I think your new link does the trick.)

Answer (score 2):

If it's a "formal document", OP should probably be *accurate*, and write...

> *This school is accredited by [Maryland State Department of Education](http://marylandpublicschools.org/)*

...since they're presumably the relevant authority, and that's what *they* call themselves. The general principle being that the "referent" of any proper noun is the primary authority in such matters.

---

But in more general contexts where we don't know (or don't care) which particular "arm" of the state is involved, or what they call themselves, capitalisation is gradually falling out of favour...

[image]

Comment: The good old 'height is popularity' metaphor. Graphically illustrated. I'm nicking 'The general principle being that the "referent" of any proper noun is the primary authority in such matters.'. Though [FumbleFingers] won't look as convincing as [Pullum] or [Chomsky].

Comment: As the "primary authority" in my own case, I think [FumbleFingers] looks *extremely* convincing (I see no [PullUm] or [ChomSky] to contradict me! :) And I trust you will [defend to the death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Beatrice_Hall) my right to insist on FFing awkward capitalisation for my own nick!

Comment: He Who Must Not Be Named.